# Very Basic Question about Kepler's Second Law of Planetary Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, planets

In order to derive Kepler's $2$nd law, in the lectures we have used the conservation of angular momentum, where we defined the trajectory of a planet in a two dimensional plane (the plane where the rotational motion of the planet takes place) in terms of the polar coordinates in the following way: $$\vec r(t)=\rho(t)\ \vec e_\rho$$ What I can't understand is the reason why the trajectory is dependant on only $\rho$ and not on $\varphi$. Since the planet is rotating with time, shouldn't there also be an angular dependancy, how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position does depend on the angle. This dependency is hidden in two places:

- Using your notations, $\rho$ depends on $\varphi$, as you can see with the canonical equation of an ellipsis):
  $$\rho(\varphi)=\frac{p}{1-e\cos(\varphi)}$$
- The unit vector $\vec{e}_\rho$ also depends on $\varphi$, since its direction changes over time.